# Remove role and recovery the role in the table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

for a mistake. I used a wrong command. I wanted to remove an user' role from the table aspnet_UsersInRoles.
I guess that the command might be

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(userName, origin_role);
```

However I used a wrong command mistakenly.

```
Roles.DeleteRole(origin_role,false);
```

Originally the table has 4 roles. Now the RoleId in the table only has two,

```
61572264-4935-461d-9d8c-71f147f28c34
c09f25e6-fd6a-447b-8e0d-eba0cfc94e40
```

How can I find and recovery them?
Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you find the source code for the function you called.
It calls the dbo.aspnet_Roles_DeleteRole stored procedure.
I don't have access to an asp.net membership database at the moment, otherwise I would check for you.
You might want to check what the stored procedure does, but as ssyladin mentioned I doubt you will be able to recover anything (since you sent the throwOnPopulatedRole argument to false).

```
public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            SecUtility.CheckParameter(ref roleName, true, true, true, 256, "roleName");
            try {
                SqlConnectionHolder holder = null;

                try {
                    holder = SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(_sqlConnectionString, true);
                    CheckSchemaVersion( holder.Connection );

                    SqlCommand    cmd     = new SqlCommand("dbo.aspnet_Roles_DeleteRole", holder.Connection);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;

                    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, ApplicationName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@RoleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, roleName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@DeleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty", SqlDbType.Bit, throwOnPopulatedRole ? 1 : 0));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int returnValue = GetReturnValue(cmd);

                    if( returnValue == 2 )
                    {
                        throw new ProviderException(SR.GetString(SR.Role_is_not_empty));
                    }

                    return ( returnValue == 0 );
                }
                finally
                {
                    if( holder != null )
                    {
                        holder.Close();
                        holder = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, but you're hosed.  The default ASP.Net providers don't include any sort of auditing or soft-delete.  If you have a database backup, you can explore/restore from that.